# Negative score limit for Questions to show in any of the tabs?

Tags: support, questions, user-interface, voting

First, apologies if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find it.

I was looking at various queries on Data Explorer earlier and noticed something a bit odd, this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765525/ has a -38 score (before this draws more attention to it anyway).

This is the lowest score I had come across thus far, so again curious I checked out the lowest net-score questions by sorting all questions by votes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

If you go the the last page though, I'm seeing -18 scores on the lowest questions.  Is there some sort of threshold for the questions displayed? I *assume* there's a `> -20` clause or something, but I'm curious.

For a more complete list, I added a query to Data Explorer: [Top (Bottom?) 20 Lowest Scoring Questions](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/7623/top-bottom-20-lowest-scoring-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765525/python-sudoku-programming) as the very last one in the search results you linked to. Just above it is a [-21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072903/invert-a-stack-without-using-extra-data-structures), a [-19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644242/get-drive-information-free-space-etc-for-drives-on-windows-and-populate-a-mem), and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268555/whats-your-most-fantastic-line-of-code-optimization) [-18s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296135/can-you-explain-what-this-code-fragment-is-doing). Are you possibly ignoring certain tags that those questions match?

---

[image: Screenshot of the search results]

Comment: Doh, you are dead on, I'm ignoring only a handful of tags and python was one of them.  Looks like the other [was merged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156363) as well (which I guess doesn't reflect correctly in the data dump).

Comment: @Nick It was just merged a week ago; the data dump is only released at the end of the month

Comment: I read that as "Jun 11" twice...definitely time for bed, thanks for confirming I am indeed crazy :)